# Why does Date.now() return a different value every time it is called?

Tags: javascript, utc

I typed this in my console repeatedly 5 times:

```
Date.now();
```

each time I get different value:

1. 1411325746046
2. 1411325746707
3. 1411325747247
4. 1411325747731
5. 1411325748204

the difference between each value is way more than I had expected...

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Because time is passing by perhaps... ;-)

Comment: Because, believe it or not, time passes ...

Comment: What offset did *you* expect?

Answer (score 3):

`Date.now()`, strangely, doesn't actually return the date. Instead it returns the number of milliseconds since the 1 January, 1970, 00:00:00 [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

So every time you type "Date.now()" into your console, I'm guessing maybe half a second or more have elapsed between calls. So you can expect the difference to be quite large, since it returns milliseconds which elapse extremely quickly.

You can read more on MDN, see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: @Shai Eilat It actually does return milliseconds, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Description

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fast you run, time may stand still, but not always.  We can demonstrate this principle using a sampling technique frequently used in science -- in the below code we will examine a MILLION cases and see if the time stand still or not.

```
var i = 1000000;
var stat = {}
while (i-- > 0) { 
   var diff = Date.now() - Date.now(); 
   stat[diff] = stat[diff]+1 || 1; 
}
console.log("Sample Result:",stat)

"Sample Result:" { '0': 999889, '-1': 111 }
```

As you can see, in most cases (999898) the time does in fact stand still, while in 111 it does move.  It is however not clear if the time moved forward or backward.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not help

Answer (score 0):

Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (the Unix Epoch.)